# Revolver and 12$ bills

Tags: plot-explanation, revolver

I just watched the movie [*Revolver*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolver_(2005_film)) and I noticed that they use 12$ bills; after a quick wiki-search I found out that they do not exist.

Why do they use 12$ bills as if they were actual currency?

Comment: probably because printing up tons of actual, or even actual-looking, currency is illegal, but printing up tons of obviously fake currency is just entertainment.